# Cloned Arch system does not use entire display with xorg

Tags: virtualbox, arch-linux, xorg, clonezilla, xorg.conf

Following situation:
I have an extremely barebone Arch Installation, that I created in virtualbox.

Installed packages are:
Grub
Plymouth (splash screen)
Ly (Desktop Manager)
Xorg
Focuswriter
That's about it, basically, if we ignore everything that arch needs and respective dependencies.
On the VM everything worked normally, I then cloned the virtual machine with clonezilla and cloned it again from file to a new computer.
Everything works perfectly expect for one thing:
Focuswriter is a Fullscreen application, but when launched it does not fill the entire screen, it's like glued to the top left corner and leaves a couple centimeters of room to the right and the bottom of the screen and when I move the cursor to the blank space, the cursor becomes an X.

Steps taken:
Reinstalled Intel video drivers (Intel internal for Celeron dual core gen 2)
Uninstalled them and installed mesa
Added a .conf file in etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/.
So far, nothing helped. Any suggestions aside installing a window manager, or a desktop environment are very welcome!

Best regards!

Comment: Perhaps Focuswriter saved some window size information in a file while it was in the VM, and is reusing this instead of getting the size from X11. Look in the home directory of the user it runs under.